# Crystal Reports XI: Summing values by unique ID in Detail Section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

list,

I am trying to sum by unique ID in the details section of Crystal Reports:

```
Unique ID    Amount_Expected
001          $ 200
001          $ 300
002          $ 200
003          $ 150
002          $ 200
003          $ 150
```

My hope is to turn the above data set so that the totals for each unique ID also show up in the row with the record, like so:

```
Unique ID    Total_Amount    Amount_Expected
001          $ 500           $ 200
001          $ 500           $ 300
002          $ 400           $ 200
003          $ 300           $ 150
002          $ 300           $ 200
003          $ 300           $ 150
```

I want to be able to group the report by ranges for Total_Amount (i.e. 500+, 300-400, etc.), which I have already been able to do for Amount_Expected.

I have already tried to use the running total fields and group by ID, but that did not work for me.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Running total field grouping by ID is the correct way to do it. Something must not be set up correctly. In SQL, `select sum(Amount_Expected) group by Unique_ID` works as desired (just tested it). This is the same as using a running total field grouping by ID. Can you post screenshots of your running total settings and grouping? Also show where you are placing the fields in your report. There must be something small slightly off.

Comment: Moreover, what did it do for you if it didn't work? That would probably help find the error too.